# Type changes after processing through inheritance function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, inheritance

A type=DataFrame object processing in a masking function defined return in a type=list.

I am trying to use inheritance to shortcut and make life easier as there are a lot of alike code. But it return out in a list rather than a DataFrame.
I have lots of alike code like:

```
df4=df3.drop_duplicates(['TITLE'])
#from df3 find title duplicated items
index2=df3.duplicated(['TITLE'])
#duplicated titles items are dropped into df5
df5=df3[index2].reset_index(drop=True)
#items with same title but different database are dropped
df6=df5.drop_duplicates(['TITLE'])
#from df5 find title duplicated items
index3=df5.duplicated(['TITLE'])
#duplicated titles items from df5 are dropped into df6
df7=df5[index3].reset_index(drop=True)
```

The inheritance class where the function is defined:

```
class Mask_TITLE:
    def __init__(self,masked):
        self.masked=masked
    def mask(masked):
        return [masked.drop_duplicates(['TITLE'])]
```

By doing :

```
>>df1=Mask_TITLE.mask(df)
```

df1 is returned as a list.

How to make sure that df1 is still a dataframe by modifying the function, or is it just inheritance and function is not possible to use in DataFrame conditions?

Comment: I believe it is the fact that you have `[]` around `masked.drop_duplicates(['TITLE'])`. Also, you're missing a `self` in `mask` (unless you intend it to be a `staticmethod` or equivalent...it's not very clear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're turning it into an list here:

```
def mask(masked):
        return [masked.drop_duplicates(['TITLE'])]
```

The `[` & `]` around the return value make it a single-element list

Try this:

```
def mask(masked):
        return masked.drop_duplicates(['TITLE'])
```

Comment: A `list`, not an array.